# Associating a query string value with a list of ajax results - AngularUI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This **[demo (click)](http://plnkr.co/edit/YdE4ixkqd0kBvcxEriLW?p=preview)** should clearly demonstrate my goal.

I just need to associate the url with a list of ajax results. Here are the circumstances:

1. User types into input field and clicks "search". The url is updated with `queryVal=whateverValue` and the ajax call is made to look up that value. The results are populated in the view.
2. The user directly visits the page with `queryVal=whateverValue` in the query string. The ajax call should immediately be made and results populated in the view.
3. The submits several values and/or navigates through other views, then uses the back/forward buttons. The url should revisit each `search` value and the corresponding ajax call should be made and the results shown.

This seems like very basic behavior, but I am new to UI Router. Just to show that I have been trying, here's some of my probably silly attempts (you may want to just ignore them).

I started out putting a `$watch` on `$state.params.queryVal` and running the ajax call, but that didn't work out with the history. I also tried several variations of this:

```
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Home' }
  });
  $stateProvider.state('home.search', {
    url: '?queryVal',
    controller: 'resultsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/home-results.html',
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Home' }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `$state.go()`? In your plunker example:

`$state.go('home', { queryVal: $scope.queryVal });`